"Fixed" effects when using mgcv and 'bs=fs' in GAMM?
I am curious what the most appropriate way to estimate both the overall/population level smooth effect of x while also estimating random smooths for different levels of a random factor (e.g. testing location) would be.
I am asking because the following models produce similar, but far from identical estimates of the random smooths.
My first thought was to include a separate smooth term for x, like so:
mod1 <- gamm4::gamm4(y ~ s(x,bs="cc") + s(x,site,bs="fs",xt="cc",random=~(1|site))
This seemed to provide a reasonable estimate of the overall, or "fixed" effect of s(x). However, I then compared the smooth estimates for s(x,site) to a model that does not include a separate smooth term for s(x), like so:
mod2 <- gamm4::gamm4(y ~  s(x,site,bs="fs",xt="cc",random=~(1|site))
The smooth effects in mod2 seem to look a little more consistent with each other and more similar to what you see if you just fit the model separately for each level of site. But there is no fixed effect of x here. Is there a way to still get a population or fixed effect from mod2 for x?
More broadly, which of these would be most sensible to fit if you were interested in the overall effect of x, but also in capturing the random smooth across sites?

This is a bit of a can of worms as you can't really do this. We have a comment/footnote or similar in our Hierarchical GAMs paper (Pedersen et al 2019) on this.
What we can do is fit a global or average smooth plus subject specific smooths, one option for which is your first model. I'm not sure why you have your random effects nested within the s() calls - I presume this is a typo here and not something you did in practice.
Say we have covariate x and a factor f coding for the subjects, then you can fit an average smooth plus subject-specific smooths with
y ~ s(x, bs = "cr") + s(x, f, bs = "fs", xt = list(bs = "cr"))

the first smooth above is the average smooth; it is a smooth through all the data. The second smooth (really a family of smooths) are random smooths, one per level of factor f. All of the individual smooths in the fs basis share the same wiggliness penalty (hence have the same wigglinesses, but different shapes).
Note the fs basis includes random intercepts (subject means) and slopes and if sully penalised so it has no penalty null space, so it can be shrunk out of the model entirely if the data do not support the effects. As such you don't need separate random intercepts etc in the gamm4() call and you can use this in gam() and bam() as well to fit GAMMs using those other functions with wider support for other conditional distributions.
If you want to allow the subject-specific smooths to have different wigglinesses, then you have a couple of options. In the HGAM paper we used
y ~ f + s(x, bs = "cr") + s(x, by = f, m = 1, xt = list(bs = "cr"))

where we have:

parametric group (subject) means (the plain f),
a global or average smooth, and
a factor by smooth, which creates one smooth per level of f.

note that for the subject-specific smooths, we have to set m = 1 to get a first derivative penalty. This has the effect of turning the factor by (subject-specific) smooths into difference smooths as any deviation from a constant zero function is penalised against. We have to do this because otherwise the average smooth and the subject-specific smooths are not uniquely identifiable. If you have limited number of unique values of the covariate x, using m = 1 can induce piecewise linear behaviour in the smooth, which is often undesirable.
Since we wrote the HGAM paper, Simon Wood added the "sz" basis to mgcv. This implement truly orthogonal smooths that solve the identifiability issue I mentioned above. As such, for many examples of the models of the kind you want to fit (but not all models covered in the paper) you would do better now using
y ~ s(x, bs = "cr") + s(x, f, bs = "sz", xt = list(bs = "cr"))

note that now we don't need the parametric effect for the group means (these are included in the "sz" basis) and we no longer need the m = 1 bit.

Hi Gavin, thank you so much for your reply (and yes, I had a typo in my parentheses, sorry about that)!

I had not seen the sz basis, so I will look into that as a solution.
Overall, it sounds like what you recommend mirrors what I was thinking the path would be. I think what I was unsure about was how adding both terms in the model would influence the fitted smooths. Will the "average" smooth really be akin to an average across all the sites, or will it be more conditional on the site effects (those that are not penalized out of the model). Conversely, are the site smooths deviations from the average?
Also, is there any problem with letting gamm4 estimate the random intercept?

One more question on the sz framework. Do you have a sense of what exactly the significance test is that is being performed? If there are multiple levels of a factor, does a low p-value mean that the difference smooth for at least one level of the factor is non zero? And is there an easy way to figure out which levels have a CI that does not include zero?

The average smooth (we called it the global smooth in the Pedersen et al 2019 HGAM paper) is not the effect for population average in the sense of a population-level effect in a mixed model. It is certainly conditional on the other terms in the model. I'm not sure I have a good, simple, explanation for this smooth actually represents. As for the site effects, we try to set these up as deviations from the average; hence m = 1 on the by smooths, and the sz basis is designed to be orthogonal too the average smooth (and hence a difference).

On the gamm4::gamm4() points: no, but as the "fs" basis already includes the random intercept you don't want to include that effect in the model twice.

As to your most recent comment; the test in the summary() output is best thought of as an omnibus test over the set of smooths (which include the group means), in the same way that an F test is used for an entire linear model while t tests are used for specific model terms. The only way to figure out which groups are higher etc would be to plot the fitted values and / or use the marginaleffects to conduct say average predictions or comparisons over the smooth covariate.
